# Retrieving AVPlayerItem from Gallery Asset

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, avasset, avplayeritem

I'm trying to play a video using the `AVPlayer` and an `AVPlayerItem`.

Im using following code:

```
asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(new NSUrl(GalleryURL));
playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(asset);
playerItem.AddObserver(this, (NSString)"status", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, IntPtr.Zero);
player = new AVPlayer(playerItem);
```

the property `GalleryURL` is one of the following:

1.) When **saving a video to the gallery**, i get this url from the ALAssetsLibrary instance call: `WriteVideoToSavedPhotosAlbum(url, (galleryPath, error) => { ... });`

where "galleryPath" is something like this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0D510365-4A63-425B-840C-A4E18BD870A8/Documents/...
```

this works fine, I can create the AVAsset and retrieve the AVPlayerItemStatus, especially the status "ReadyToPlay", via the added Observer.

2.) However **when I retrieve a Video from the gallery**, the url looks different:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=EB9FC214...
```

and in this case I'm **not** able to retrieve a working AVAsset

How can I get part 2 to create a working AVAsset, which  I can use for video playback? I believe this works in iOS versions prior to iOS 11.

Comment: Are you using `UIImagePickerController` to retrieve your video from 
photo album? If so, in the event when you finish picking it `FinishedPickingMedia()`, there are two types of urls you can choose in the `info` dictionary(an original like "assets-library://..." and another one like "file:///..."). But both of them should be played properly.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the tip, I will try to find it out. I'm actually using the xamarin media plugin to open the gallery and pick a video. I think I have to make changes in this file, in the method `GetMovieMediaFile(NSDictionary info)` starting at line 528: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/ccb2dbea342b4b58a30fc7d795a93218214e42ab/src/Media.Plugin.iOS/MediaPickerDelegate.cs#L528

Comment: I'm just not sure yet whether to use MediaURL or ReferenceURL

Comment: As I said both urls can be used. One is original source, another may be compressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landu Lu - MSFT helped me to find the answer:

He told me that there are 2 paths that I receive from the UIImagePickerController:

The asset-library path could not be used, maybe I have to remove the "assets-library:" part? but the path beginning with "file://" could be used. The problem of the plugin was, that the start of the url was cut off, there was no "file://" at the beginning. I manually added this string and it works! Thanks alot!